# Fragment is not attched to parent when application goes to background for long time

Tags: android, performance, fragment

I have a fragmentA which has ViewPager which contains couple fragments lets say FragmentA-1 and FragmentA-2. If i keep app in background for more than 10 minutes and open app again, Fragment inside(i.e. FragmentA-1, FragmentA-2) viewpager get detached.

But click events of the view inside FragmentA-1 and FragmentA-2 works fine and when I try to update UI from parent fragment i.e. FragmentA then it shows view as null;

```
 mFrontPhotoFragment = AddCardPhotosFragment.newInstance();
    mBackPhotoFragment = AddCardPhotosFragment.newInstance();
    mCardsFragment.add(mFrontPhotoFragment);
    mCardsFragment.add(mBackPhotoFragment);
    PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), mCardsFragment);
    mCardsViewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
```

This happens on specific devices with low configuration. How can i fix this

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think you can do that. You can either save the data in SharedPreferences or SQLite (which ever suits you according to your need) because Android will kill your app if it's inactive for some time to free RAM memory for other applications.

Answer (score 0):

In view pager, Fragment might be recycled it some times. Try setting page limit.

You can call `viewpager.setOffscreenPageLimit(k)` to cache all entities of `ViewPager` from `n-k` to `n+k`.